# Is there an open source implementation for bag-of-visual words?

Tags: image-classification, computer-vision

I'm not quite sure I understand the bag-of-visual-words representation, so I may misformulate my question.

What I'm currently looking for is an open source library (possibly with python API). I give it pictures as input, and its output is a set of (sparse) features, so that I can perform my stuff base on this features. Idealy, I would like this piece of software to work without internet connection (so that I can work with it while in the plane).

**EDIT**: I just learnt that facebook recently (summer 2016) released some of its image recognition code (namely [multipathnet](https://github.com/facebookresearch/multipathnet), [deepmask and sharpmask](https://github.com/facebookresearch/deepmask))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one implementation of BoVW in openCV. You can find the documentation here :

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/object_categorization.html